# Detecting voice call support in mobile devices using titanium

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

However, not all mobile devices support phone calls, such as the iPad.

How can I programmatically determine whether a device supports voice calling or not using titanium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to detect device capabilities. But there are several workarounds depending on what you want to do:

1. You can create a wrapping method, that tries to detect the phone capability: On iOS this is easy, only the iPhone is able to do voice calls. On Android it's a bit different. Usually only handhelds can do phone calls but their are also some tablet devices that are able to.
2. If you simply want to present a phone number that the user can klick on you can create a link with `Ti.Platform.openURL('callto:<number>');`. There is also a `canOpenURL()` method - but its not available on android.

The `canOpenURL()` method would be useful especially for android to determine whether the system is able to do phone calls or not. This question was also dicussed on [Appcelerator Q&A](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/134522/determining-device-capabilities).

Conclusion: Detecting capabilities needs to be solved on your own. In one of my apps i used the second solution regardless the device is able to do phone calls.

Comment: Thanks VVoo it's working great in iOS. Do we have any alternative workaround for android

Comment: Unfortunatly not. I checked the Titanium docs again but their is no information about capabilities. The only way is to [analyze network](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network) availability because mobile network requires phone capabilities. But that doesn't mean that a 3G tablet is able to do phone calls but a 3G tablet has a SIM card and for phone calls you need a sim card.